# Regular Expression to match markdown and regular href sources from specific domain(s)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to append something to the query string to various assets hosted on filepicker which serves from a few specific domains, some of which already contain a query string.  All other URLs should be left untouched.

For example, we might have the following in markdown:

```
![image](https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/12x3DD5667dxfjdf/convert?w=600)
```

We could also have

```
<img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/someotherfile" />
```

Or

```
<a href='https://www.filestack.com/api/file/anothersdf?sdf=3&dfdf=1'>link</a>
```

Just trying to match against one domain for the moment I have the following regular expression which isn't matching all cases:

I do not want to match any references to other domains.

I've had mixed success with the following:

```
/(https:\/\/www\.filepicker.io\/api\/file\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\/convert)*[^)])$/is
```

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regular expressions.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7008354)

Comment: Less is more with Regx...  `www.filestack.com` is not `www.filepicker.io`, that said `/(https?:\/\/www\.(?:filepicker\.io\/|filestack\.com\/)api\/file\/[\w+?&=\/]+)/` https://regex101.com/r/DA8Gok/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match what you want:

```
 /(https?:\/\/www\.(?:filepicker\.io\/|filestack\.com\/)api\/file\/[\w+?&=\/]+)/
```

https://regex101.com/r/DA8Gok/2/

But Regex is not well suited (by itself) to parse any type of structured data.  Instead make a lexer/parser.

Here are some examples of ones I have written:

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Lexers

http://artisticphoenix.com/2018/11/11/output-converter/